# How to retrive User Information from post ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am developing HelpDesk application using ASP.NET.CORE 5.0 MVC and right now I want to retrive User information from ticket, like `UserName,LastName,Email etc`
So far I create a little guide using SQL Query

```
 SELECT u.Id as UserId,
         u.UserName as Username,
         u.Email as UserEmail,
         t.UserId as TicetUserId
  FROM AspNetUsers u,Tickets t
  WHERE u.Id = 2 and t.UserId = 2
```

So far I want to write this in C# using `LINQ` and `_unitOfWork`.
I will try to demostrate my Models starting from basic one which is `Ticket.cs`

```
public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kratak Opis")]
        [MaxLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Maximalan broj karaktera je 20")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
        public string DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        //[Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka")]
        //public DateTime Answered { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta tiketa")]
        public int TicketTypeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TicketTypeID")]
        public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();

    }
```

From TicketModels I have alredy ApplicationUser class and `UserId` which is `ForeignKey` to `ApplicationUser`

And in ApplicationUser.cs I have all property which I need to retrive

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ime")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Adresa")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Grad")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postanski broj")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        //[NotMapped]
        //public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
    }
```

But basically most property which I need is `UserName`,`EmailAddress`.
Is there some way to figure out something like this, since I am begginer in RepositoryPattern and UnitOfWork and it is a little bit confusing me and whatever I try to retrive data I get wroong output.
I try something like:

```
 var userEmail = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(t => t.Id == ticketId);
```

This will retrive `TicetId` which is correct. But how to get TicetId base on UserId ?

Comment: in your `ApplicationUser` model, it look slike you do not have a `UserId`...

Comment: Yes, I have it.
https://imgur.com/nTmzSXE

Comment: I just inherit from IdentityUser

Comment: As your Ticket has `UserId`,you can use `var userEmail = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(t => t.UserId == userId);`

Comment: Yes, and I get userId, but how to get other User infromation, like `Email` ?

Comment: You can add  `public string Email{ get; set; }` to ApplicationUser,and then get Email from userEmail.

Comment: I have alredy have Email field, it is inherit from `IdentityUser`

Comment: Can you share your userEmail data when you use `var userEmail = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(t => t.UserId == userId);`?

Comment: I solve the problem. Thank you very much for you advice and helps. Cheers !